# Adding an IF ELSE to a function

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

This is my code, but I only want echo the code if the current category has children.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
    'parent' => get_queried_object_id(),
]);
echo '<div style="height: 200px; text-transform: uppercase; border:1px solid #666666; padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll;">
<div class="breaker-small">Refine Search</div>';
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<p class="filters"><a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';
}
echo '</div>
<br />';
?>
```

So, if

```
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
    'parent'   => get_queried_object_id(),
]));
```

True - then run the echo.

Comment: That's pretty basic PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this code like below-

```
<?php
$element = get_queried_object_id();
if (!empty($element)) {
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => $element->taxonomy,
        'parent' => $element,
    ]);
    echo '<div style="height: 200px; text-transform: uppercase; border:1px solid #666666; padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="breaker-small">Refine Search</div>';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<p class="filters"><a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';
    }
    echo '</div><br />';
} else {
    // Do something
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `count()` to count the number of entries in `$terms`. Here is the code-

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => get_queried_object()->taxonomy,
        'parent'   => get_queried_object_id(),
        ]);
    echo '<div style="height: 200px; text-transform: uppercase; border:1px solid #666666; padding:10px; overflow-y: scroll;">
    <div class="breaker-small">Refine Search</div>';

    if( count( $terms ) ) :

    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
        echo '<p class="filters"><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></p>';  
    }

    endif;

    echo '</div>
    <br />';
?>
```

[Not tested]